# HTML is deleting when opening DevTools

Tags: html, devtools

On one of the website I faced with such code in the HTML in script tag:

```
if (debug = "localhost" === window.location.hostname,!debug) {
    var element = new Image
      , devtoolsOpen = !1;
    element.__defineGetter__("id", function() {
        devtoolsOpen = !0
    }),
    setInterval(function() {
        devtoolsOpen = !1,
        console.log(element),
        devtoolsOpen && window.document.write("")
    }, 1e3)
}
```

So when I open Chrome DevTools the whole HTML is deleting and the page becomes empty. Can you help, how to prevent it?

Comment: Was this a script you wrote or from a page you visited?

Comment: It's not my script

Comment: Just remove `&& window.document.write("")` from the line `devtoolsOpen && window.document.write("")`

Comment: This script is in HTML in 'script' tag so I cannot remove it

Comment: I would disable javascript on the browser

Comment: Did that, but there is <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>.

Comment: Also I've tried to disable JS, copy the whole DOM without that script, enable it again, and after this script removed HTML did ```window.document.write('copied DOM')```. But it's not working properly too. Maybe there is another better way